# How often do you "skip" on closing a question and why do you do so?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions, review

When deciding whether to close a question, one option is to skip - which is like abstaining.

How often do you do this? Why do you do so?

And, as another question, what happens when people skip?

Comment: I skip questions on topics I don't feel expert about, that are not clearly off-topic or against the rules. I skip if I have mixed feelings and no clear opinion. We have many users capable of voting, so this should not be a problem if some of us abstain from voting in some cases.

Comment: @Tim That seems like a fine answer -- and is basically identical to my own feelings on skipping.

Comment: Peter, as a moderator you have access to a complete list of reviews, including skipped ones if you request them.  Meta isn't the place to discuss such moderation tools, though: inquire in chat if you're not sure where to find this information.

Comment: What @Tim said.  About 1/3 of the time for me, the question seems OK on the surface, but I don't know enough about the subject to say whether it's definitely reasonable or definitely screwy, so I leave it to someone more knowledgeable to decide.